# What DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘God is' || NULL || NULL || ‘Great' ) displays?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

1.What DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘God is' || NULL || NULL 
|| ‘Great' ) displays?

2.Is it valid?
DECLARE i, j, k NUMBER(2);

Answer (score -1):

1.What DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘God is' || NULL || NULL || ‘Great' ) displays?

```
o/p God is great
```

2. Is it valid? DECLARE i, j, k NUMBER(2);
   No, this is statement is not valid, we should assign all these variables separately eg.

   I NUMBER(2);

   j  NUMBER(2);

   k  NUMBER(2);

Comment: Why would there be a space between `is` and `Great`, and why has `Great` lost its capital letter?